How to solve treeview going out of parent frame in python with tkinter?
I want to load and modify the contents of the Excel sheets. I am using tkinter treeview for displaying data with openpyxl.
The problem is whenever I open the excel sheet larger than the frame size, it goes out of the window and cannot be seen. I used a scrollbar hoping that I could scroll through the data with it, but that also is not working.
Below is test code for this test purpose only:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl

file_name = "test1.xlsx"

def open_excel(file_name):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = wb.active
    list_values = list(sheet.values)

    bom_tree.delete(*bom_tree.get_children())

    bom_tree["column"] = list(list_values[0])
    for col in list_values[0]:
        bom_tree.column(col, stretch=NO, minwidth=25, width=200)
        bom_tree.heading(col, text=col)

    for val in list_values[1:]:
        # print(val)
        bom_tree.insert('', "end", values=val)

root= Tk()
root.title('test2')
root.geometry("1000x600")

#create treeview frame
tree_frame= LabelFrame(root, text="tree frame" ,padx=50, pady=50, width=1000)
tree_frame.pack(padx=20,pady=20)

bom_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, show="headings", height=10)
bom_tree.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10)

#scroll bars
tree_scroll_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=bom_tree.yview)
tree_scroll_vertical.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=NS)
bom_tree.configure(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_vertical.set)
tree_scroll_horizontal = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=bom_tree.xview)
tree_scroll_horizontal.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=EW)
bom_tree.configure(xscrollcommand=tree_scroll_horizontal.set)

open_excel(file_name)

root.mainloop()

Here is a screenshot of the output:

I am using grid as it will be required for my application, but I also tried to use packing and still am not able to find the right setting.

Since the treeview is put at column 0, you can add tree_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) to make the treeview to fit into available horizontal space.
Result:


Thank you for the answer. I was trying to use column config for the tree view and not the parent frame, that was the problem. Anyway thank you for your time.

depends on your Intent for the app.
if you want your app to have a certain column limit then you could just increase the screen size.
you could implement a scroll on the excel tree view, but since you said this failed (without saying why it failed), you can just use 2 buttons instead and only show a set amount of columns each time.
and if none of these sound good, then please explain your goal with the app

Thank you for the time. I have added scrollbars in the code but horizontal scrollbar was not available as it only appear if there is something to scroll I guess. Anyway the solution provided by @acw1668 worked and I know what I was doing wrong. Thank you.
